# Next Image function from click on image, to click on link

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm customizing a image slider plugin, and would like to add a link, that when clicked, shows next image - like a clicking on the big image does.

Try the demo here: http://exposure.blogocracy.org/demos/demo1.html

I can't figure out in the code, but clicks on img.exposureImage is the same function I want.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that they are using plug-in named [Exposure plugin](http://exposure.blogocracy.org/jquery.exposure.js?v=0.5.2) for jQuery as mentioned on their homepage. From the documentation of plugin, it is mention that `clickingNavigation` is the attribute that is enabling the functionality you are talking about.

```
clickingNavigation: (boolean) Enable browsing by clicking the image being shown. Defaults to true.
```

Comment: What should the link look like? 
<a href="#" class="clickingNavigation">Next image</a> 
Doesn't work... I tried several things, but I can't make it work...

Comment: Can you paste your customized code? or link where I can see what you have done.

Comment: Try to set class as "exposureNextPage" to your link. As there is already 1 next link is present with similar functionality. Also library is loading next image on click of link with class name exposureNextPage.

Comment: I just want the function that is on the big image. When you click that, the next image appears..

Comment: to be precise "$(".nextImage").click($.exposure.nextImage);" is what you want exactly.